# MVC Updatemodel and Linq-To-Sql creates new entity instead of updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a survey form with the following data hierarchy

survey -< surveyQuestions -< surveyQuestionOptions

I use updateModel to update the Survey entity in my save method which works fine for survey and surveyQuestions, however surveyQuestionOptions appear updated when I examine the updateSurvey variable in debugger but after I call SubmitChanges I get new surveyQuestionOption records instead of updates.  My code is as follows

HTML

```
 <%= Html.TextBox("Survey.Id", Model.Id)%>
 <%= Html.TextBox("Survey.SurveyName", Model. SurveyName)%>

 <%= Html.TextBox("Survey.SurveyQuestions[0].Id", Model.Id)%>
 <%= Html.TextBox("Survey.SurveyQuestions[0].Question", Model. Question)%>

 <%= Html.TextBox("Survey.SurveyQuestions[0].SurveyQuestionOptions[0].Id", Model.Id)%>
 <%= Html.TextBox("Survey.SurveyQuestions[0].SurveyQuestionOptions[0].Option", Model. Option)%>
```

Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Save(int? id, IList<ChannelForm> channelForms, FormCollection fc)
        {

            Survey updateSurvey = new Survey();

            //if this is an existing Surveyretrieve that record from the database ready for updating
            if (id != 0)
            {
                updateSurvey = surveynRepository.GetSingle(Convert.ToInt32(id));
            }

            try
            {
                // updateSurvey and all child elements
                UpdateModel(updateSurvey, "Survey");
                surveyRepository.Save();
return View();
    }catch
{return View();}

    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I would like an answer to this also.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Survey updateSurvey;

 if (id == 0)
 {
     updateSurvey = new Survey();
 }
 else
 {
     updateSurvey = surveyRepository.GetSingle(Convert.ToInt32(id));
 }
 try
 {
   ..etc
```

Comment: yes I could do that but it doesn't solve my problem.  My Survey and SurveyQuestions are all working properly, its only the SurveyQuestionOptions where it always adds a new SurveyQuestionOption record.

Comment: Make sure that, in your GetSingle method, you are also retrieving the SurveyQuestionOptions from the database on edit.

Comment: as above the SurveyQuestionOptions are being returned and appear to be updated in UpdateModel.. just SubmitChanges that creates new..

Answer (score 0):

Mmm.. i have not tried to Update directly a child element like that, specially with Complex models (various depth levels). I mostly use a ViewModel and then use that ViewModel to Update the Actual Model(the LinqtoSQL classes).

I would Update the child's this way:

Get The Current Saved Survey

```
currentSurvey = surveyRepository.GetSingle(Convert.ToInt32(id));


foreach (var option in updateSurveyViewModel.SurveyQuestions)
{
   //check if exist
   var current = currentSurvey.SingleOrDefault(a=> a.Id == option.Id);
   if (current == null)
   {
     //Create a NewOne and attach it to the curentSurvey
   }
    else
   {
    //already exist, Update the option
    current.Option = option.Option;
    //...
   }
   }
```

I know this is not the depth level with the problem but is the same concept.

Comment: I could do them individually but would like to use UpdateModel for simplicities sake.  As I say it appears to update all the proper children and only when i callsSubmitChanges does it save new records.  Also, does your code manage scenarios where a user removes an element from a list?

Comment: Maybe another thing to check is that your second level child is loaded, yoo must do an eager load on all child elements

Comment: @Joe: Nop, it doesn't, but it could be added, it would be the opposite if current is not null instead of creating a new one just mark it for deletion surveyRepository.Delete(current);

Comment: Hi again, sorry SO isn't very good at telling you when you have a comment.  The second level of children has IsLoaded = true so why does linq create new ??

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with LoadOptions in LINQ to SQL:

```
var loadOptions = new System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions();
loadOptions.LoadWith<Contact>(c => c.ContactEmails);
db.LoadOptions = loadOptions;

Contact old = db.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContactID == id);
UpdateModel(old, "Contact");

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Didn't help. All existing ContactEmail is deleted and inserted again.